# Load a html page to a div without affecting the style outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Besides using iframe, is there method that an external html page can load to a div without affecting the style outside the div?

I use jquery load now but if the external html page define style for body, the style for the page outside the designated div is changed.

For example, I want to load this page to a div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #DEDEDE; font-size: 96px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page defined style for body and it includes an external css file. (I can't control the content of the page.)

Comment: Is there any example so we can understand what you want ?

Comment: Is this what you need?: http://jsfiddle.net/6b2m1Luk/ using CSS to prevent "overflowing".

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur I think no.

Answer (score 1):

The included html page must not contain html/body tags, styles or css inclusions if you don't want to affect your parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax instead of load and on success just remove the link tags from the success data html.